# Python pandas.to_sql error when trying too upload many columns into Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas, odbc

I have been attempting to use Python to upload a table into Microsoft SQL Server. I have had great success with smaller tables, **but start to get errors when there is a large number of columns or rows**. I don't believe it is the filesize that is the issue, but I may be mistaken.
The same error comes up whether the data is from an Excel file, csv file, or query.
When I run the code, it does create a table in SQL Server, but only has the column headers (the rest being blank).

This is the code that I am using, which works for smaller files but gives me the below error for the larger ones:

```
import pyodbc
#import cx_Oracle
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


connstr_Dev = ('DSN='+ODBC_Dev+';UID='+SQLSN+';PWD='+SQLpass)
conn_Dev = pyodbc.connect(connstr_Dev)
cursor_Dev=conn_Dev.cursor()

engine_Dev = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://'+ODBC_Dev)

upload_file= "M:/.../abc123.xls"
sql_table_name='abc_123_sql'
pd.read_excel(upload_file).to_sql(sql_table_name, engine_Dev, schema='dbo', if_exists='replace', index=False, index_label=None, chunksize=None, dtype=None)
conn_Dev.commit()
conn_Dev.close()
```

This gives me the following error:

> ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('The SQL contains -13854
>   parameter markers, but 248290 parameters were supplied', 'HY000') .......
>   (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)

The error log in the provided link doesn't give me any ideas on troubleshooting.

Anything I can tweak in the code to make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: The error is related to an unequal number of parameters expected than parameters actually provided.

Comment: And what would be the solution, given that it is auto-detecting the number of parameters, and there is such a large number of them?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to pandas 0.23.4 solved it for me. What is your version ?